# Error in the SQL query

Tags: sql

Can't figure out what is wrong with the following SQL query:

```
INSERT into ALL (name, address, client_id, service_id, service, service_address) values 
('Товарищество с ограниченной ответственностью "King Fisher"',
 'г.Алматы, ул.Айманова, 155, уг.ул.Жандосова','10','10','Интернет(1024)/10','г.Алматы, ул.Айманова, д.155, уг.Жандосова');
```

Here is an error output:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALL (name, address, client_id, service_id, service, service_address) values ('' at line 1
```

Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: whats the error in it when you execute the `insert` ??

Comment: still can't figure out, could you provide exact value without quotes?

Comment: Do you need to escape the table name `ALL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL is a reserved keyword. Because of this, it is necessary to wrap the table name in backticks:

```
INSERT into `ALL` (name, address, client_id, service_id, service, service_address) values 
('Товарищество с ограниченной ответственностью "King Fisher"',
 'г.Алматы, ул.Айманова, 155, уг.ул.Жандосова','10','10','Интернет(1024)/10','г.Алматы, ул.Айманова, д.155, уг.Жандосова');
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

you have not closed the ' quotes, check and try or try using brackets

Comment: If you look at the number of comma separated values that _are_ contained in quotes, you'll see that there are still the same number of fields as in the `INSERT` clause.  I got caught by that too at first, but look closely :)